# In Which case parent Node does not include height of child Node in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in styling , in Some case parent node/div do not include height of their child node . If any one had this problem , then please give reason .

e.g.

```
#id{
position:relative;
background:red;
}
.spacer{
  height:40px;
  position:relative;
}
<div id="x">
<div class="spacer" style="float:left;"></div>
<div class="spacer" style="float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

In `my` case `height of X node is something different than 80px` (less than 80px). Why this is happening ?

I have lot of code so i can't post all those . Please give any reason .

Comment: [this is a good article about clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float`ed elements are not counted as part of the parent's height.

Unless said parent has `overflow:hidden`.

(Or you can use a clearfix, but `overflow:hidden` is generally better)

Answer (score 0):

When all the elements inside a parent element are floated, the parent collapses if its' height is not specified.
This is a known issue with a simple solution - you need to use [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html#.U3zA5PmSx7o) on the parent element.
In this example:

```
#x:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

I recommend reading Chris Coyier's excellent article ["All About Floats"](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) for a deep explanation and solutions.